# Missing ___emutls_get_address with gcc-4.7 and openMP

Tags: gcc, openmp, dynamic-linking, gcc4.7

I am trying to compile a program using a self-compiled GCC-4.7.1 on Mac OS 10.8.2. The program uses openMP and the compilation succeeds; however, when I try to run the program, the dynamic linker complains with

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /usr/local/gcc-4.7.1/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /usr/local/gcc-4.7.1/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

This issue is constantly present in any program compiled with -fopenmp, including the MWE

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  #pragma omp parallel
  printf("Hallo!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Note that the solution suggested in [What is the "___emutls_get_address" symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885246/what-is-the-emutls-get-address-symbol), namely adding `-lgcc_eh` in the linking phase, does not work (I still get the same dyld error message).

Comment: Strange, I did compile recently GCC 4.7.1 on OS X 10.8.2 according to [this guide](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/07/21/compiling-gcc-4-7-1-mac-osx-lion/) and the OpenMP support works flawlessly.

Comment: @HristoIliev I'll check again how I compiled it and try to recompile. Hopefully the issue disappears...

Comment: A similar question and answer have been posted there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885246/what-is-the-emutls-get-address-symbol

Comment: After upgrading the version of the org.deeplearning4j from 1.0.0-beta5 to 1.0.0-beta6 it is ok.

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same problem too.
And I am new to openMP, and my skill is not that good to use the solution offered by Michal Fapso.
I solve this problem by using

```
brew link --overwrite gcc
```

and the problem is solved!

Maybe you can try to reinstall gcc to your Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem. In my case it was caused by linking against a library (I don't remember which one) of an older version of gcc installed by XCode, which was in /usr/lib. When I corrected it to link against the newer gcc library of the version I used for compiling (in /usr/local) this error was fixed.

So just check your built executable and all the libraries it is linked with using

```
otool -L EXECUTABLE_OR_DYLIB
```

And if you find anything linked with a library of an older gcc, fix that.